# have a fixed width on window resize

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML.

```
  <div class="chapter">
        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <li class="item">
                <div class="para">
                    <span class="item-num">4.</span>

                    <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">

                        <li class="item">
                            <div class="para">
                                <span class="item-num">(a)</span>
                                In Safari advanced settings I have 14MB of website data. Some entries have a large amount of data such as mail.google.com with 4.3 MB. Google Mail in Safari is web based and I have no offline content except 1 small unread message in my inbox. My contacts are not available when wifi or mobile is not connected so what is the "Webdata" and what would I delete if I deleted it?
                                <table class="frame-bot">
                                    <colgroup>
                                        <col class="colname-col1 colwidth-25%">
                                        <col class="colname-col2 colwidth-50%">
                                        <col class="colname-col3 colwidth-25%">
                                    </colgroup>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="bottom">[2014]</td>
                                            <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                                                <span class="font-style-italic">Thanks giving happy holiday
                                                </span></td>
                                            <td align="right" valign="bottom">1</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                This is content after table

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>

    </div>
```

here there is a table(frame-bot) and i gave it full width(when we maximize the browser it stretches from left to right totally), but the problem comes when i re-size my browser(shrink), here the table shrinks and becomes smaller, i.e. it doesn't touch the ends of the page. when you run the below snippet in full screen you can see the effect, and when you re-size it, the table becomes even more small.

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix this.

```css
div.chapter ol.orderedlist li.item div.para ol.orderedlist li.item div.para table.frame-bot {
  width: 106.5%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-left: -7em;
}
.orderedlist {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  margin-left: 1.85em;
}
.orderedlist .item {
  list-style: none;
}
.orderedlist li.item div.para {
  margin-left: 0em;
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}
.orderedlist li.item div.para span.item-num {
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-indent: 0em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
.orderedlist .orderedlist {
  margin-left: -2em;
}
.orderedlist .orderedlist li.item div.para {
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.orderedlist .orderedlist li.item div.para span.item-num {
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  margin-right: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter">
  <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="para">
        <span class="item-num">4.</span>

        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">

          <li class="item">
            <div class="para">
              <span class="item-num">(a)</span>
              In Safari advanced settings I have 14MB of website data. Some entries have a large amount of data such as mail.google.com with 4.3 MB. Google Mail in Safari is web based and I have no offline content except 1 small unread message in my inbox. My contacts are not available when wifi or mobile is not connected so what is the "Webdata" and what would I delete if I deleted it?
              <table class="frame-bot">
                <colgroup>
                  <col class="colname-col1 colwidth-25%" />
                  <col class="colname-col2 colwidth-50%" />
                  <col class="colname-col3 colwidth-25%" />
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="bottom">[2014]</td>
                    <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                      <span class="font-style-italic">Thanks giving happy holiday
                                                </span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right" valign="bottom">1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              This is content after table

            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your issue? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/tg7jx4sq/)

Comment: Hi, @jbutler483, here is an update (i added some text to show the issue). (http://jsfiddle.net/tg7jx4sq/2/), here when you stretch the output screen fully, the table width matches the content width, but when you shrink it, it goes small er than the content width, i want this fixed. i mean the table width should match content width irrespective of stretch or shrinking the window. - Thanks

Comment: Ok what seems to be the issue is that you have it structured in a way that the table is taking its size from the container, rather than the page itself.

Comment: Yes, is there any alternative by maximizing the width or so..